# why do variables in namespaces break into the global scope, and what should I do to address this?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'd like to have arrays in my namespace which all functions in the namespace can access.

Is there no way to do this without resorting to names like `$_MYNAMESPACE1_NAMESPACE2_NAMESPACE3_array1`? I suppose I could make a class in the namespace which contains static arrays, but that seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: That's not how name spaces work: http://php.net/namespaces

Comment: I understand how namespaces work. I'd just like to be able to have arrays in my namespace, just as I'd put `const`able objects, classes and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot namespace variables. You can only namespace classes, interfaces, functions and constants. Since variables outside functions can only be accessed using the `global` keyword, and `global` is usually an anti-pattern, this is probably not the solution you're looking for anyway. A class seems like the way to go.

Comment: Anti-pattern: it depends. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357187/when-are-global-variables-acceptable